# most efficient (and pythonic) way to concatenate strings in python without leaving immutable chunks behind

Tags: python, string

Let's say that i have 2 strings that i want to concatenate:

```
item = '123'
item_2 = '456'

item += item_2

print(item)
```

the output will be:

```
123456
```

That's exactly what i wanted! But as we all now, python strings are immutable objects, so after the execution of the given code, we'll have 3 strings stored in memory:

```
'123', '345' and '123456'
```

So my question is: What is the most efficient (and pythonic) way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The original `'123'` string will be cleaned up by the garbage collector, so there will only be 2 strings in memory.

Comment: This is how you concatenate strings. It's not clear what you mean by more 'efficient' or even 'pythonic' in this case.

Comment: As you say, Python strings are immutable, so there's no way to concatenate in place, it has to make all these copies.

Comment: If you have a list of strings that you want to concatenate, use `.join()` rather than a loop that concatenates each of them separately. It will use an efficient algorithm to build the result in one place rather than O(n**2) copying.

Comment: it`s not a list, is a sequence of class attributes that aren't related

Comment: well, you can use `del` to explicitly delete something as long a nobody else have a reference to it